# ios core data union query

Tags: ios, core-data

Is it possible to do union of two queries (from the same entity) in core data? In SQL speak, if entity is called t, then consider that T has following data:

```
+------+------+------+
| x    | y    | z    |
+------+------+------+
| 1    | 11   |    2 |
| 1    | 12   |    3 |
| 2    | 11   |    1 |
| 3    | 12   |    3 |
```

Then I am trying to run the following query (using core data - not SQLite)

```
select x, y, sum(z)
from t
group by 1, 2
union
select x, 1 as y, sum(z)
from t
group by 1, 2
order by x, y, 1
;

+------+------+--------+
| x    | y    | sum(z) |
+------+------+--------+
| 1    | 1    |      5 |
| 1    | 11   |      2 |
| 1    | 12   |      3 |
| 2    | 1    |      1 |
| 2    | 11   |      1 |
| 3    | 1    |      3 |
| 3    | 12   |      3 |
+------+------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: There are no responses as of yet. Did you figure this out and would you care to share it here if you did?